# how does Redis cluster keyspace work? can't recive redis expired event

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

according to the document
(https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/)

**Events in a cluster**

Every node of a Redis cluster generates events about its own subset of the keyspace as described above. However, unlike regular Pub/Sub communication in a cluster, events' notifications are not broadcasted to all nodes. Put differently, keyspace events are node-specific. **This means that to receive all keyspace events of a cluster, clients need to subscribe to each of the nodes**.

Does this mean that I should subscribe to the slave nodes? Besides master node?

For example, if it is an expired event

Slave nodes only replicates master nodes, and when the data expires, doesn't the event occur in master nodes?
Shouldn't I just only subscribe to the master nodes?

Why should I subscribe to all nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean that I should subscribe to the slave nodes? Besides master node?

It means you need to subscribe to all master nodes in the cluster.

> Does this mean that I should subscribe to the slave nodes? Besides master node?

No. Normally you don't want to subscribe to slave nodes. Because slave nodes might send different notification messages from master nodes. See the following for example.

> Slave nodes only replicates master nodes, and when the data expires, doesn't the event occur in master nodes? Shouldn't I just only subscribe to the master nodes?

When data is expired, subscriber on master node will get an *expired* notification. When master expires the key, it will send a *del* command to slave node, so that slave will delete (expire) the key. Since slave node receives a *del* command, subscriber on slave node will get a *del* notification. That's the different.